# Ask about web programming study order

Tags: web, network-programming

1. HTML5.1 / CSS3
2. JavaScript (jQuery / Node.Js)
3. CentOS Server Or Windows Server
4. PHP Or JSP Or ASP
5. MySQL or Oracle DB or MsSQL

No. 1 is being studied right now. I'm wondering where to use jquery and node.js in # 2. I do not know whether to use Linux server or Windows server in 3. Same as # 4, # 5 and # 3.

**Is there anything else I should learn?**

Comment: 2. javascript >nodejs >jquery .. // because jquery is framework over js which make the task easier.

Comment: You should use linux server .

Comment: if you learn nodejs perfectly there is no need for PHP or JSP and ASP(as for this you need window server )

Comment: Mysql is good for beginner , but you can try mongodb which is also a good option .

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Thank you!

Comment: prepare yourself for the amazing path of web developer , it can be boring if you only try to learn the technology , so keep yourself busy with small  projects ... best of luck ...